# How can I keep mediawiki not-yet-created pages from cluttering my google webmaster console with 404s?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, mediawiki, seo-audit

we have a mediawiki install as part of our site.  As on all wikis people will add links for not yet created pages (red links). When followed these links return a 404 status (as there is no content) along with an invite to add content.

I'm not getting buried in 404 notices in google webmaster console for this site.  Is there a best way to handle this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404s do not directly affect your rankings.

404s are bad when the user is expecting there to be a page and there is not as this can badly affect user experience which can indirectly affect rankings.

If you just want to solve them to make your search console data look neat then you would have to stop the search robots from crawling  the pages.

If there is a clear pattern to the URL then you could use the robots.txt file them remove this when the page exists.

If there isn't then I don't see there being any safe way of stopping these 404s from being reported without changing the functionality of the site itself (To not create 404 pages)

Comment: Thanks that's what I feared.  The issue is when you have 15k such 404's in your report it means you can't see stuff that is meaningful and it take a month to clear them all out.

Comment: In the search console does it tell you where these pages are linked from?

Comment: I know where they are linked from.  In mediawiki you can create links to pages [[page_to_link_to]] and this is used as a means to gauge the popularity of a request, so it's a feature.  Until that page is created though it returns a 404.  It's the red links on wikipedia pages.